# How to call c# function in xsl

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

im trying to call a c# function in xsl. I have to map some values into a xml. There are 3 principal components

-xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" 
xmlns:ns0="http://iti/serv/dataloader"
xmlns:HelpersNS0="http://ri/clus/mapperhelpers/v1.0/I/F/C/CustomComponents ">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
<xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='InvokeDataLoader']">
<ns0:scriptToExecute>
<xsl:value-of select="HelpersNS0:GetDataLoaderPath()"/>
</ns0:scriptToExecute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

-xml where i get c# assembly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<ExtensionObjects>
<ExtensionObject
  Namespace="http://ri/clus/mapperhelpers/v1.0/I/F/C/CustomComponents"
  AssemblyName="G.T.I_Fatt.CustomComponents, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6ecedb456a4a8c16"
  ClassName="G.T.I_Fatt.CustomComponents.MapperHelpers"  />
</ExtensionObjects>
```

-xml to transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<InvokeDataLoader xmlns="http://iti/serv/dataloader">
<scriptToExecute/>
<inputFile/>
</InvokeDataLoader>
```

But when i try to transform i get this error: "namespace does not contain any functions"

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? The extension mechanisms for Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6datxzsd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. You can use "script" blocks with C# or VB code inline or you can use extension objects where you need to pass in your extension object using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. The snippets you have posted don't use either of the both mechanisms. So which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: Actually im using Xtrans tool to test it, but ill use visual studio and Biztalk maps to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have `xmlns:HelpersNS0="http://ri/clus/mapperhelpers/v1.0/I/F/C/CustomComponents   ts">` in the XSLT yet `Namespace="http://ri/clus/mapperhelpers/v1.0/I/F/C/CustomComponents"` (without the `ts`) in the other file. So the namespace does not match.

Comment: Even after the edit you have different URLs, at least in your posted samples, `"http://ri/clus/mapperhelpers/v1.0/I/F/C/CustomComponents "` versus `"http://ri/clus/mapperhelpers/v1.0/I/F/C/CustomComponents"` where the former has a blank at the end. That would suffice to make the URLs different. Other than that I don't see an obvious problem but I am neither familiar with Xtrans nor Biztalk. You might want to edit the tags of your question so that someone with expertise in those areas can look over the samples.

Comment: I solved it. I created maps and extension object directly into Biztalk so i could associate xslt to extension object and load the dll. i was trying to find another method to do that without Biztalk but i didnt find it. Thank for ur help